# JSON formatting drill down issue

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo's arrayUtil.forEach to loop through my JSON object but when I get to data.graphs.metrics it does not continue because metrics is not an array. What options do I have?

```
xhr("/esp/files/eclwatch/ganglia.json", {
  handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data){
      arrayUtil.forEach(data.graphs, function (item, idx) {
         //never gets here.
      });
   });
}




//json file
 {
  "graphs": [
   {
    "name": "Bar",
    "metrics":{
      "metric": ["metric1, metric3"],
      "metric": ["metric1", "metric4", "metric5"]
     },
    "time": ["Hour", "Month", "Week"]
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `metrics` is an object, and contains two keys with the same name. your `1/4/5` entry will overwrite the the `1/3` entry anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it an array instead of giving it duplicate keys would make the most sense.

```
"metrics": [
   ["metric1, metric3"],
   ["metric1", "metric4", "metric5"]
 ],
```

Comment: Awesome! You made my life so much easier.  I was going to do `"metrics":[metric:["metric1","metric2"]]` but was not valid JSON on JSONlint. Thanks @Quentin